# How to search for a forward slash using the strrchr library function in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

For some reason, whenever I try to find a slash at the end of a byte string (in this case, base_url which is set to "www.google.com/"), it doesn't seem to want to return that it is or isn't there. However, if I change base_url to something like "www.google.com" where m is the last character, then it finds it just fine.

```
//in this case, the base_url is "www.google.com/". I also tried to simply put "www.google.com/" in place of the base_url, just in case.

char * last_char_ptr;
last_char_ptr = strrchr(base_url, '/');

if(last_char_ptr == NULL)
{
 cout << "it is null!" << endl;
}
else
{
 cout << *last_char_ptr << endl;
}
```

Whatsup?

Comment: works okay for me: http://ideone.com/oH5xt

Comment: Why don`t you use `string::findXX`?

Comment: Is base_url a std::string or a char*?  Try printing it where you print the error and you might see that it is not what you expect.

Comment: It is a char*. I am required to only use the cstring library, otherwise I would be using normal strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you do but this works for me:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const* ptr = strrchr("google/", '/');
    std::cout << (ptr? ptr: "<null>") << "\n";
}
```

That is, it prints a forward slash. If you code comes up with `it is null!` something went wrong before reaching this code.

Comment: Wow. Now I have learned that it doesn't just search the END of the string. It searches the entire string for the LAST occurrence of a character. I have now been corrected!